# need converting from V1 to V2 AHK?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I've just converted my V1 script to V2.

This script is supposed to execute some code after launch a specific program :

```
; =================================================================
; V1
SetTimer error_script2, 1000
error_script2() {
    static appWinTitle := "script2.ahk.ahk ahk_class #32770"
    static runningIds := []
    ; get the ID of the topmost window that matches the exe
    WinGet id, ID, % appWinTitle
    ; if at least one window exists, check it against the known list of running windows
    if (id) {
        newInstance := true
        Loop % runningIds.Length() {
            if (runningIds[A_Index] = id) {
                newInstance := false
                break
            }
        }
        if (newInstance) {
            WinWaitActive,script2.ahk.ahk ahk_class #32770
            SetDarkWindowFrame(WinExist("script2.ahk.ahk ahk_class #32770"), 1)
            Sleep 100
            WinSet,AlwaysOnTop,On
            WinActivate, ahk_exe Code.exe
            ; WinWaitClose,2kha.ahk ahk_class #32770
        }
    }
    ; repopulate the list of running window IDs
    WinGet currentPids, List, % appWinTitle
    runningIds := []
    Loop % currentPids {
        runningIds[A_Index] := currentPids%A_Index%
    }
}
; =================================================================
; V2
SetTimer(error_script2, 1000)
error_script2() {
    static appWinTitle := "script2.ahk ahk_class #32770"
    static runningIds := []
    ; get the ID of the topmost window that matches the exe
    id := WinGetID(appWinTitle)
    ; if at least one window exists, check it against the known list of running windows
    if (id) {
        newInstance := true
        Loop runningIds.Length {
            if (runningIds[A_Index] = id) {
                newInstance := false
                break
            }
        }
        if (newInstance) {
            WinWaitActive("script2.ahk ahk_class #32770")
            SetDarkWindowFrame(WinExist("script2.ahk ahk_class #32770"), 1)
            Sleep(100)
            WinSetAlwaysOnTop(1)
            WinActivate("ahk_exe Code.exe")
            WinWaitClose,script2.ahk ahk_class #32770
        }
    }
    ; repopulate the list of running window IDs
    ocurrentPids := WinGetList(appWinTitle, , ,)
    acurrentPids := Array()
    currentPids := ocurrentPids.Length
    For v in ocurrentPids
    { acurrentPids.Push(v)
    }
    runningIds := []
    Loop acurrentPids.Length {
        runningIds[A_Index] := acurrentPids[A_Index]
    }
}

; =================================================================
```

The V1 was working well But in V2 I've got this msg error :

Error: Target window not found.
id := WinGetID(appWinTitle)

Any help to solve the issue please ! Or If there is an alternative to it?

Comment: Well [WinGetID](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/WinGetID.htm) will throw an error if the target window could not be found, you could use [WinExist](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/WinExist.htm) instead since you're already handling the fail scenario with the `if` statement right afterward